# Angular dist files huge, causing slow download

Tags: angular, performance, build, download, production

Ever since upgrading my Angular app to version 5, then version 6, it's been downloading very slowly in the browser, sometimes taking well over 30 or 40 seconds. Though I'm optimizing the build for production, (`ng build --prod --build-optimizer --aot`), the core files add up to over a megabyte.

The main offenders are

- `main.1acde84f0c61a49d6387.js`, which is 831kb,
- `styles.99d75733e80daf42e5f9.css`, which is 269kb, and
- `0.06cf948c35f50dabe8dc.js`, which is 243kb.

[image]

Are these files typically so large? Any idea how I can trim them down and improve download speed?

Comment: likely, this is caused by 3rd party libraries bundled with your app.  If you can, use "ng eject" and get the webpack configuration.  Add the webpack-bundle-analyzer plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to find out which 3rd party is causing the large bundle size.  Then set it up as an external script reference (preferably a CDN) rather than as part of the bundle.

Comment: I added the webpack-bundle-analyzer plugin. Here's a screenshot of the output: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bkdcbg30yct56b5/Screenshot%20from%202018-06-26%2013-35-12.png?dl=0. I can't identify anything that shouldn't be there ...

Comment: I see a few 3rd party libraries that you could separate out (lodash.js, url.js).  Are you using @angular/cli or webpack?  From what I can see, you should be able to get your bundle size down to about 100Kb (main.js) if you can separate out your vendor bundle from your app bundle.

Comment: Lazy loading modules will help too.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have angular-cli listed in `package.json`, and I'm building from the command line. Does that mean I'm using angular-cli? I didn't realize it was either-or. I would love to separate the vendor bundle from the app bundle, though I'm not sure how. Is this what `ng eject` is for?

Comment: yes, if you're using "ng  build" to build your app, then you're using @angular/cli.  "ng eject" is for ejecting from the cli, so that you can customize your webpack build.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://nitayneeman.com/posts/how-to-add-third-party-library-in-angular-cli/

Comment: Hmm, I see that the "scripts" array is empty in my .angular-cli.json. Is that a telltale sign? Should I try to find CDN's for lodash.js and url.js and add them there? Also, as inspired by the article, I tried replacing instances in which I was loading the entire lodash library with only loading the method I'm using, e.g. `import { omit } from 'lodash/omit';` This didn't seem to have any effect on the file size of the main.js.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is **you bundle all your application inside one module**.

It means all your pages,components,... will bundle in one file, it surely will be heavy.

The solution here is you should separate your application to more smaller bundles. In `Angular` it called is `module lazy load` and implement `preloading`(optional) to decrease `bundle size` at first time loading.

You can follow these articles:

- https://coryrylan.com/blog/custom-preloading-and-lazy-loading-strategies-with-angular
- https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Or follow these steps:

- Make a module for a your page, it also includes its necessary components.
- Routing for this module
- Use `loadChildren` to load this module at `app router`. Something like that:

  `{ path: 'a', loadChildren: './anynomous/anynomous.module#AnynomousModule' },`

Comment: Good call. I did have most everything grouped into a single module. I followed the tutorial you linked to and created new modules and new child routes for lazing loading. I now see 4 additional files in the dist folder, such as `1.b06a3b4d3470560595fb.js`. However, download time has not improved, as my `main.a346bfb6bc1d7f56862f.js` is still over 800kb. (It actually got a little larger.) As experiments, I tried commenting out every route in `app.routing.ts` and reducing `app.module.ts` as much as possible, but still the main.js file was about 800kb. There must be something else I'm missing ...

Comment: I not sure about your app scenario, but you should separate all pages, components of your app into corresponding modules. Example: your first page is login page, so you just need to load the module **only** for `login`. it will take few kb. And `1.b06a3b4d3470560595fb.js` it called is **chunk**, and with the normally application we have **~60 chunks**, with large app we have more than it. Should modular our app.